# How to Change The State Of An Element While hovering on Another Element Using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, queryselector

I am trying to change an item while hovering on another one, using `mouseover` event and `querySelectorAll` methods. Frankly I don't know what is wrong with my code, anyone help?

```
var navBar = document.getElementById('nav');
var navLiAnchor = navBar.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a');
var navIcons = navBar.querySelectorAll('ul > li > span > i');

for (var i = 1; i < navIcons.length; i++) {
    navIcons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        if(navIcons[i].style.color == 'gray'){
        navLiAnchor[i].style.color = 'gray';
        } else {
            navLiAnchor[i].style.color = 'lightgray';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: did you try `:hover` css?

Comment: Do you mean to skip the first element in your array by starting at `i = 1`

Comment: My answer addresses the issue with the JavaScript; however, after taking a closer look, @NidhinJoseph correctly points out that the same thing could be achieved with just CSS with only minor changes to your markup.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that you are adding an event listener in a for loop. Generally this is considered bad practice, and your case is a good reason why, as it causes a bug.

See: https://gomakethings.com/why-you-shouldnt-attach-event-listeners-in-a-for-loop-with-vanilla-javascript/

> The i variable isn’t scoped to the loop # After each iteration of the loop, the i variable increases by 1. The value does not remain constant within the scope of your event listener callback function. It changes.

Refactor your code so that the event handler does not reference the counter variable in the parent scope. In your handler you can use `this` to refer to the target element (you can also use `Event.target`):

```
var navBar = document.getElementById('nav');
var navLiAnchor = navBar.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a');
var navIcons = navBar.querySelectorAll('ul > li > span > i');

for (var i = 0; i < navIcons.length; i++) {
    navIcons[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        var idx = navIcons.indexOf(this);
        if(this.style.color == 'gray'){
            navLiAnchor[idx].style.color = 'gray';
        } else {
            navLiAnchor[idx].style.color = 'lightgray';
        }
    });
}
```

(Also, as @SmujMaiku pointed out, you probably intended your loop to start at the first element, index `0`.)